# JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal continuation byte 0xa

Tags: java, android, androidx

```
     java_vm_ext.cc:594] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal continuation byte 0xa
     java_vm_ext.cc:594]     string: 'arch_disk_io_�
     java_vm_ext.cc:594] '
     java_vm_ext.cc:594]     input: '0x61 0x72 0x63 0x68 0x5f 0x64 0x69 0x73 0x6b 0x5f 0x69 0x6f 0x5f 0xe0 0xa7 <0x0a>'
     java_vm_ext.cc:594]     in call to NewStringUTF
     java_vm_ext.cc:594]     from boolean android.os.Process.readProcFile(java.lang.String, int[], java.lang.String[], long[], float[]) 2023-02-07 18:26:40.796 13309-13331/om.friendimobile.vm D/VRI[SplashActivity]: dispatchAppVisibility visible:false
```

This is what I am getting in my logcat after this application closes.
I know **arch_disk_io_�** this string is causing issue but this string is used in `DefaultTaskExecutor` class in androidx dependency so I don't know how can I solve this.

Also I am getting this issue in few devices.

Comment: It looks to me that *something* has started a thread/process with a weird non-UTF-8 encoded name and then *something else* in the Android code chokes on that. I don't see a way that the `DefaultTaskExecutor` could accidentally do this, so it's likely to be a different code (probably some predecessor with similar goals?) You say you get this on a few devices, can you reproduce it locally or do you only have statistics of this problem?

Comment: @JoachimSauer for a few devices it's reproducible. and it's happening only when I open the app after killing the app. when I change the language and use the app without killing from recents its working fine the moment I kill the app forcefully and open it again it causes the above crash.